# dual input temperature comparison circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, relay

I would like to build a comparator circuit that will compare two varying  temperatures and operate a relay to a fan when one is greater than the other, but release the relay if the opposite is true. I would like to build in a small differential in temperatures before the relay will operate, something like 10 degrees.  I would like this to work at low temperatures and at higher temperatures,( example; on at 40 degrees sensor 1 while sensor 2 is at 30 degrees for low, and on at 100 degrees while sensor 2 is at 90 degrees for the high side.)  Of course temperatures would need to be translated to resistances or voltages. Using something like the diodes used in thermostats or thermistors or such.
While looking through the site I could find circuits that compare to a fixed setting  and others that are adjustable, but I would like to compare two varying  temperatures and get and output. These examples seem to use op-amps as a well suited comparator. A single input voltage would make it simpler, some low voltage such as 12v dc or 24v ac would be best. 
I haven’t worked much in the electronics side of circuits for about 40 years, but do remember and could relearn much about the components needed. My first electronics class in college used slide rules since simple calculators were just starting to appear! I’m sure there is a lot out there that I haven’t heard of since those times!
thanks for any help.
Rex

Comment: What sort of temperature range?  Any choice for a temp sensor?    Some hysteresis on the comparator should take care of the small differential that you need.  (Oh and what side of circuits is not electronics?)

Comment: Your right, electronics are everywhere, my work has been on the electrical side mostly, but I'm low in electrical design. The temperatures I am working with are between 30 degrees and 100 degrees. As for the sensor, I'm looking at components that are readily available, as long as they will do the job.

Comment: OK then is it a one of, or are you going to make thousands?  Industrial sensors, or something DIY like Sperho's diode connected transistors (below)  I was going to suggest thermistors, which will match a bit better, but will cost more.

Comment: it's a one item, simply to evacuate the air in the attic of the garage to the unheated garage below. Simple as that. Thanks Rex

Comment: Did you ever solve this? How did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple circuit that should do the trick. It's a kind of [Wheatstone bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) with a comparator. The two transistors should be from the same lot- they'll typically be matched to within < 1°C. If you need to trim them so they're exactly balanced, you can trim R5 or R6.

Take care as to the layout- the path from M1 back to the supply should not go through any of the analog circuitry- millivolts count.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIycbW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: Since you want to have a non-zero nominal differential, you'd adjust the resistance R5 or R6 to get the differential (for example, you could replace R5 and R6 with 1.8K resistors and connect them with a 500 ohm pot instead of directly, with the wiper going to the + input of OA1. There will be a small effect on the differential with absolute changes using this circuit. You would adjust the difference to about 2mV/degree C differential, so if you wanted 5°C differential you'd adjust the pot to get something like 702mV/712mV from the + input to ground vs. the + input. If the absolute temperature changed 25 degrees C then the differential would change by about 7%, so about 0.35°C out of 5°C.

Edit2:

Photo of transistor test:

[image]

Comment: Nice... though I might have used a bit less current through the diodes... self heating and all that.  I've not used the 2N3094's as diode temperature sensors.  but TIP32's show a variation of +/- 3-4 mV (at 300K) all from the same batch... so I might add the tweaker resistor to R5/6.  Why the caps across the base emitters?  Noise reduction?  (Do they need to be right near the transistor sensors?)

Comment: Yes, as shown near the transistors. I'd like them to behave sensibly. Quite possibly not necessary, but cheap insurance. Self heating is an issue- but it should be similarly matched to each other and maybe 0.3°C so some part of 1/3°C... If I reduced the current much then the value of R4 would start to get too high because R4 and R6 would have to be increased. Trade-offs..

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Just for kicks I picked four pieces 2N3904 out of the engineering stores (at random, but out of one bag of bulk transistors), soldered them together in series with 5.0K to 13.2V (2.07mA). Allowed them to stabilize and all four measured 0.707V on my 3.5 digit handheld meter. Not too shabby.

Comment: Diode connected or "bare" Vbe?  I had a helper match up some diodes by Vbe, and then found that when I made the collector- base connection the "matching" no longer matched.  (These were the big tip23's mentioned above.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Diode connected (see photo above). A quick measurement with VBE using the diode function on a multimeter showed much more variation! (different transistors, however, SMT ones).

Comment: Thanks, If used as a temp sensor then much of the heat will couple in via the collector lead.  (More so for smd packs.. later.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the circuit and info. I had no idea that transistors could be used for sensing temperature. could you please explain a little of what happens to the transistors when they warm and cool? I'm supposing that the conductance from collector to Emitter must change some how.

Comment: @rexweston If you put a fairly constant current (the 4.7K resistor to 12V) through a diode then the forward voltage will be about 0.6-0.7V and will change by about -2mV/°C (fairly linear). A diode-connected transistor makes a more [ideal diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation) than a rectifier like a 1N4148 and it's probably easier to work with physically as a sensor.  Eg. 2N3904 sim at 20/30/40/50/60 C -> 699/682/666/649/632mV

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 digital temperature sensors (e.g. DS18B20 based), connect these to an Arduino nano along with a relay module and write a simple code in C.
This way you can easily re-configure it by changing the code (e.g. add hysteresis, maybe a humidity sensor etc.).
Can't beat that with an analog circuit. It will cost you less than $10.

Comment: Thanks so much for a new insight of what can be done with this interesting little device. Once I mentioned it to my son studding Chemical Engineering, He knew exactly what you were getting at and wanted to take over the project, but he had to leave and won't be back to help for a while. So the project remains mine. I'll study up on the Arduino and how to use it, then make a decision on building a circuit as described by others or using the Arduino and some of the supporting sensing equipment. Thanks for the new insight.